# I need a thread in Web/JavaEE container to complete AsyncContext objs in same JVM

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0

I need a thread in Web/JavaEE container to fetch information from an external source and complete corresponding AsyncContext objs in same JVM.

I wish to have a zero-added-latency solution, so periodic polling or a timer is ruled out.

I could start a thread but I believe it is frowned upon in a Web container and not portable. **Q1. Is it possible to run a thread portably in a Java EE container instead?**

**Q2. If I want to run a thread in a Web Container anyway, what is the "least of all evil" ways?**  InitializeContext? ExecutorService? Thread.run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AsyncContext.html#start](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#start%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is probably the closest you can get.

Comment: wow, great find! btw, what is the intended purpose of AsyncContext.start() ? Does AsyncContext.complete() wait for the thread started by AsyncContext.start() to finish before completing?

Comment: From my understanding of the specification: `start()` is intended for pieces of work that you want to happen outside the request handling cycle, `AsyncContext#complete()` does not wait for the thread to complete

Answer (score 1):

You can use work manager in jsr237 for creating a thread in a Java EE container. : http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237. If you want an asynchronous job, you should use JMS.

Comment: hi, thank you, but the JSR you point to is inactive / withdrawn. do you know whether something similar exists in Java EE 6?

Comment: It isn't an official feature but it still exist in many application server (was, weblogic, jboss). But I think that you can use http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcommonj.myfoo.de%2F&ei=A8eVT_GXMoTV8gO8vYGUCg&usg=AFQjCNE78zKX6Fhw6xt94t4fdKdmMOzuNg&sig2=RVbso0A2IpLqdk4eSUvAJg  I never tried commonj but used work manager in WAS some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

In Java EE 6, you can put the `@Asynchronous` annotation on an EJB method to have the work in that method be handled by a special thread-pool:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBean {

    @Asynchronous
    public void doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else, inject this bean and call the `doSomething()` method. Control will return immediately.

```
@WebServlet("/test")
public class SyncServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        someBean.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Note that you might **not** need something like `AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync()` here. You would use this only if the asynchronous code would still need to send something to the response.

If you need something akin to a period timer though, and not do something in response to a request, you can use the timer service in a singleton:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class SomeTimerBean {

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/30", second = "0", persistent = false)
    public void doStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Instead of running periodically, you can also run something like this once using the `@TimeOut` annotation:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class SomeTimerBean {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Postconstruct
    public void init() {
         timerService.createSingleActionTimer(0, new TimerConfig(null, false));
    }

    @Timeout
    public void doStuff(Timer timer) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can have variants on this, e.g. `SomeTimerBean` can also call an `@Asynchronous` method in an *other* bean as well to basically have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer. Sorry I did not notice it earlier.  It will take me a bit of time to fully understand it and see if it applies to my situation.

Comment: I am not sure if it applies to my situation thought. The timer is ruled out because I do not want to poll. That leaves the stateless bean asynchronous method. I feel that method is designed to perform relatively small pieces of work rather than a thread that runs for a very long, indefinite period of time, as long as the application is up. Theoretically I could fire the asynchronous method on startup and it would never finish. But I am not sure if that is frowned up on in Java EE architecture to have an extremely long running method of a stateless bean.

Comment: Perhaps I could have the method be called "back-to-back" (directly or indirectly call itself when one iteration of its forever loop finishes)?  In contrast, the other answer, which I have currently selected as the "right" answer, has a method for starting a real thread which can run forever. It is pretty unusual to see that in Java EE and I was surprised, but it seems pretty genuine and I do not see any architectural or design considerations against having it run for ever.

Comment: >has a method for starting a real thread which can run forever. - I'm not sure that this is any different from `@Asynchronous`. An AS will rarely if ever create a thread on demand. In practice, for both of them a thread from a pool will be used. So if the work takes an indefinite amount of time, you will have "eaten up" one thread. This is a little peculiar indeed, but hardly a deal breaker if it's only 1 thread. In case of @Asynchronous, you do need to disable transactions, as by default these will be active and these do have a timeout (typically 5 minutes).

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, and there is exceptionally good content in your answer. However, for an indefinite thread, the semantic meaning of `AsyncContext.start()` is closer to that of a long-running thread, and thus I prefer it over your suggestion. The downside is that you can only fire the thread upon getting a servlet request rather than on initialize, but I am overlooking that in favor of the clarity of semantics. Thank you again for your great answer! (and I will be happy to have you correct me if I am wrong in any other way).