# Java EE: Track progress in MessageDrivenBeans on cluster

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, cluster-computing, message-driven-bean

I have a message driven bean that is instantiated on a cluster node whenever a message arrives in a queue.

I want to be able to monitor and cancel the processes that are running in the message driven beans clusterwide, which is a bit of a problem.

How can that be achieved? Can I somehow obtain lists of the MDBs that are currently processed from each cluster node and kill their processes if necessary? Can I use some sort of singleton to hold references of all the MDBs on all cluster-nodes (I don't think so :( )

Is there some registry service I could use or is it possible to write something like that?

May last resort is to drive the monitoring and cancellation process via a database, which I dislike because it requires polling the database in the MDBs to detect a cancellation, which would otherwise be a simple flag that is set.

The server environment is BEA Weblogic 10.02 and I am using EJB 3.0!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with MDB's but a solution could be to have a clustered singleton bean which each MDB links into to register an id. It can then check back with the same bean using the id it registered with to detect cancellation. In essence your DB based solution but without the polling of the DB.

I don't think MDB's are supposed to be very long running and should probably delegate to threads which are better manageable.

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/websphere/0738426091/message-driven-beans/ch06lev1sec7

The above talks about MDBs in EJB2 (Couldn't find EJB3 reference online).  relevant section:

"*Do not use for real long-running transactions*— Although we indicated that asynchronous request/reply might be appropriate when the request is too long running for the MDB client to wait for, we are not saying the MDBs themselves should be used for long-running transactions. This might be better left to a batch cycle, or some other activity that breaks the work into smaller executable components. The MDB can be the launching point for coordinating the activities of the complete long-running transaction."

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd really like to delegate to specs BUT: the ejb spec does explicitly not support creating your own threads. The containers behaviour is undefined then. I really want to stick to the spec. As for the singleton service: Yes, it's doable but then you have a tight coupling to whatever container you use (in my case weblogic).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276028/i-need-a-thread-in-web-javaee-container-to-complete-asynccontext-objs-in-same-jv may help in terms of spawning threads in accordance with the spec. It will all of course be much easier if you are using Java EE 6. i.e. you could use use the Singleton bean  for the service so that you adhere to the spec.